# Using MongoDB for approved / pending

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a client that want to have a collection of offers from partners, but they need to approve changes. What would be the best way to keep history of changes from their partners?

So here is how it works

```
{
partner_id: {here}
offer1:
offer2:
offer3:
date:
status:
}
```

I need a way to check if any offers changed (but only 1 back) and if changed insert and make the past one as status:history

There should only ever be the following status:

history
pending
approved

but if they are inserting a new offer but there is an approved one, then it needs to stay approved until we approve it.

How can I do this? This is how I thought:

```
    <?php

    function checkoffers($data)
    {
    $this->data = $data;

    $collection = $this->db->partner_offers;
    if($this->data["_id"] != null)
    {
      $cursor = $collection->insert(RUN INSERT ARRAY)
    }
    else
    {
      $cursor = $collection->find(array("_id"=>new MongoId($this->data["_id"])));

      if ($cursor->count() > 0)
        {
            $test = array();
            while( $cursor->hasNext() ) {   
                $test[] = ($cursor->getNext());
            }


                     foreach($test as $offers)
                     {
                      check to see if offer matches the past offer. if not then run new function and insert.
}


                 }


    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to organize your schema with a document per offer:

```
{
    partner_id: 123,
    offer: 'Even better than the last one',
    date: ISODate("2012-08-28T10:00"),
    status: 'pending'
}
{
    partner_id: 123,
    offer: 'The best of the best',
    date: ISODate("2012-08-28T09:00"),
    status: 'approved'
}
{
    partner_id: 123,
    offer: 'An offer you cannot refuse',
    date: ISODate("2012-08-28T08:00"),
    status: 'approved'
}
```

Then you easily find the latest approved or pending offer sorting by status and date:

```
> db.partner.find({partner_id:123, status:'approved'}).sort({date:-1}).limit(1)

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("503c6c8be16d4a06b6f0da17"),
    "partner_id" : 123,
    "offer" : "The best of the best",
    "date" : ISODate("2012-08-28T09:00:00Z"),
    "status" : "approved"
}
```